# Are non-allergic, non-pathogenic rhinitis associated with fever?

Tags: immune-system, allergy, nose, fever, runny-nose

Among common causes of rhinitis are

- irritants
- weather changes
- infection (e.g. common cold)
- allergy (e.g. hay fever)

One way to disentangle between infection and allergy in presence of rhinitis is by the presence/absence of fever. Indeed, allergies never triggers fever (see [Why don't allergies cause fever?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82558/why-dont-allergies-cause-fever)), while infections often do.

Can non-allergic, non-pathogenic rhinitis (e.g. irritant and weather change) also be associated with fever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Common cold,** which is an acute viral infection of the nose, is *rarely* associated with fever in adults ([Canadian Medical Association Journal](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3928210/) ; [DPHHS Montana](https://dphhs.mt.gov/Portals/85/dsd/documents/DDP/MedicalDirector/CommonCold101713.pdf)).

**Allergic rhinitis** *does not usually cause fever;* it's not mentioned as a symptoms on major clinical websites ([Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/134825-clinical#showall) ; [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/departments-centers/allergic-diseases/minnesota/overview/specialty-groups/allergic-rhinitis) ; [MedlinePlus](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000813.htm)). [News In Health](https://newsinhealth.nih.gov/2014/10/cold-flu-or-allergy) says allergic rhinitis "never" causes fever, while [The Journal Of Allergy and Clinical Immunology](https://www.jacionline.org/article/S0091-6749(95)70211-3/fulltext) says that fever "is rarely found in patients with allergic rhinitis."

**Non-allergic rhinitis** (irritant, vasomotor, hormonal, medicamentous, gustatory, senile, etc.) is also not associated with fever according to various sources ([Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/874171-overview) ; [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/nonallergic-rhinitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20351229) ; [World Allergy Organization](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3650992/) ; [Allergy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28474799)). After some further research, there seems to be no evidence that non-allergic, non-infectious rhinitis would be associated with fever, but I can't exclude the possibility that sometimes could be.

**In conclusion,** the absence of fever does not help (much) in determining the type of rhinitis.